# how to make list in ionic + angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

I am trying to make a list with accordion features.
I try to learn from [here](http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/uJkCz) and try to make my own problem accordion [list](http://play.ionic.io/app/03ec7aab6667).
I am able to make collapsible list But when I am external object I am not able to make collapsible list.

Could you please tell me how to make this list as shown in image when I have external object.

here is my [code](http://play.ionic.io/app/af672c108f46):

```
  $scope.groups = [];
  for (var i=0; i<collect.length; i++) {
    $scope.groups[i] = {
      name: i,
      items: []
    };
    for (var j=0; j<collect.childItems[i].length ; j++) {
      $scope.groups[i].items.push(i + '-' + j);
    }
  }]
```

Comment: What is the actual question here? "I am unable to make a collapsible list" isn't really a question.

Comment: http://play.ionic.io/app/4e3c87ed103f please check this ..I am not able to get correct data in child view

Comment: Again, "I'm not able to get correct data" isn't a *question*.

Comment: sorry ok I will try my best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need to push your `collect` array of items into another array. 
The [codepen](http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/uJkCz) you're linking does that cause they're creating a fake array from scratch.

You simply have to store your `collect` into your `groups`:

```
$scope.groups = collect;
```

Even if you could simply put the array of object straight into you `$scope.groups` without defining the `collect` object.

and change your HTML so that it can loop the correct way:

```
  <ion-list>

    <div ng-repeat="group in groups">
      <ion-item class="item-stable"
                ng-click="toggleGroup(group)"
                ng-class="{active: isGroupShown(group)}">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                  <div class="custIcon"><img ng-src="{{group.iconURL}}" /></div>
              </div>
              <div class="col col-80 listHead">{{group.name}}</div>
                <div class="col"><div class="item-icon-right"><i class="icon" ng-class="isGroupShown(group) ? 'ion-ios-arrow-up' : 'ion-ios-arrow-down'"></i></div>
              </div>
        </div>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item class="item-accordion"
                ng-repeat="item in group.childItems"
                ng-show="isGroupShown(group)">
          <div class="internalRow">{{item.childName}}</div>

      </ion-item>

    </div>
  </ion-list>
```

The `ng-repeat` here uses the sub-collection `childItems` existing in the `group` object:

```
<ion-item class="item-accordion"
                ng-repeat="item in group.childItems"
                ng-show="isGroupShown(group)">
          <div class="internalRow">{{item.childName}}</div>

</ion-item>
```

this is the [sample](http://play.ionic.io/app/c134de6659d3) you might need.

**UPDATE:**

This is an adaptation with sub-items:

```
    <ion-list>

        <div ng-repeat="group in groups">

          <ion-item class="item-avatar item-icon-right" ng-click="toggleGroup(group)" ng-class="{active: isGroupShown(group)}">
            <img ng-src="{{group.iconURL}}">
            <div class="item-text-center item-text-wrap">{{group.name}}</div>
            <i class="icon" ng-class="isGroupShown(group) ? 'ion-ios-arrow-up' : 'ion-ios-arrow-down'"></i>
          </ion-item>

          <ion-item class="item-accordion item-icon-right" ng-repeat="item in group.childItems" ng-click="toggleSubGroup(item)" ng-show="isGroupShown(group)">
              <div class="item-text-center item-text-wrap">{{item.childName}}</div>
              <i class="icon" ng-class="isSubGroupShown(item) ? 'ion-ios-arrow-up' : 'ion-ios-arrow-down'"></i>

              <div class="item-accordion sub-item" ng-repeat="child in item.grandChildren" ng-show="isSubGroupShown(item)">
                  <div class="item-text-center item-text-wrap">{{child.grandChildName}}</div>
              </div>

          </ion-item>

        </div>

    </ion-list>
```

We have 2 `<ion-item>`. The first one controls the second with `toggleGroup(group)` on `ng-click`.

The second  contains a `<div class="item-accordion sub-item">` which is manipulated by its parent via `toggleSubGroup(item)`.

[image]

This is the [source](http://play.ionic.io/app/40f60f097fb2), just in case someone is interested ... and a [codepen](http://codepen.io/Leftyx/pen/KdqeVj) as well.

Comment: what is wrong in that I am able to do like that http://play.ionic.io/app/4e3c87ed103f

Comment: there is problem In your solution ..Please check image .."Record To Report" have two children "Framework Assets" and "Solution Assets" ..I need to show his grandchildren below ."Record To Report"

Comment: please check the image and see the expected result

Comment: If you send me the draft with the things to do and your project I can finish it for you. No worries.

Comment: No I just want the logic behind how to itrate the object..Actually the problem is that I have nested list ..In which i have headers ..But

Comment: No I just want the logic behind how to itrate the object..Actually the problem is that I have nested list ..In which i have headers ..But inside that there is another header and have childs

Comment: Updated answer with some explanation and a [new link](http://play.ionic.io/app/40f60f097fb2) to the ionic play. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

There is a javascript error in your code:

```
WRONG: collect.childItems[i].length
RIGHT: collect[i].childItems.length
```

Better:

```
$scope.groups = [];
collect.forEach(function(item, i) { 
  var group ={
    name: i,
    items: []
  };
  $scope.groups.push(group);
  item.childItems.forEach(function(child, j) {
    group.items.push(i + '-' + j);
  });
});
```

Comment: Please check image .I need to display text instead of 0-1, 1-1

Comment: if you don't want to display 0-1, 1-1 then define another text. What is the problem?